# duda acerca de marcadores de google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

tengo un par de marcadores en mi aplicación android, los cuales se visualizan correctamente, lo que quiero hacer es, obtener el titulo de un marcador y abrir una snackbar con la información que actualmente muestran mis marcadores (punto, titulo, snippet, icon), tras buscar un poco, encontré el método gettitle(), pero lo que no logre encontrar es la sintaxis de como utilizar dicho método, si pudiesen ayudarme con documentación acerca de la sintaxis de este o algún ejemplo similar a lo que deseo hacer, estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Es decir, ¿quieres abrir un mensaje en cada uno de los marcadores?

Comment: @zhet agrega tu código en el cual creas los marcadores si deseas más ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas un [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker), defines un titulo:

```
 GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
 // Add a marker at San Francisco.
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

Ese titulo puedes obtenerlo mediante el método [getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getTitle()), este titulo puedes almacenarlo en una variable y mostrarlo en tu SnackBar.

El obtener el titulo se puede realizar cuando das click al `infoWindow` (map es la instancia de tu Google Map):

```
 map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){

                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "El titulo de este marcador es: " + marker.getTitle(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 

                }
            });
```

Comment: gracias amigo, me solucionaste el problema :D

Comment: Que bien , saludos @zhet,

Comment: existe algun metodo que sea al hacer click en el mercador y no en el dialogo que este abre?